# JS limit the number of decimal places in a number

Tags: javascript

I have a js that grabs values, multiplies, sums, divides, and then puts them in a cell of a table. The result can be up to (I think) 15 decimal places. How do I limit it to two?

ex.:
Result of math operation: 5.223567
I want: 5.22

I want to truncate or round the remaining decimal places. I am open to solutions that requires resources outside of js but would prefer a js solution if one exists.

Answer (score 16):

Use `.toFixed`.

```
yourNumber.toFixed(2);
```

Notice that `.toFixed` will return a string, as JavaScript uses 64 bit floating point numbers which cannot guarantee accuracy. (In layman's terms, JS cannot represent 0.1 accurately so it has to return a string.)

Comment: Nice explanation of why toFixed returns a string.

Comment: He didn't say he wanted a string though.

Answer (score 6):

```
 (5.223567).toFixed(2)
```

the method toFixed rounds to a number of decimals.

Comment: why downvote when the answer is perfectly valid. Even no comment explaining why this is perceived incorrect.

Comment: Trivial questions with easily discoverable dupes are asked a lot in this tag. Users get tired of it, and downvote answers to these questions.  There's more info over on [meta], if you search for it.

Comment: I understand, will try to add comment to the trivial questions ;) instead of an answer.

Comment: It'll probably save you downvotes in the future. Good luck.

Answer (score 5):

If you do not want to use .toFixed() you could also

```
Math.round(num * Math.pow(10,x)) / Math.pow(10,x)
```

where x is the number of decimal places and num is the original number